# What are different ways to configure an eventbridge schedule rule type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I'm working on a solution where I've an eventbridge rule and it's of Schedule type rule. And based on the schedule frequency the rule will call a lambda function for further computation. I'm aware of configuring a rule having event pattern using API Gateway service, but wanted to know is there any was I can configure the schedule frequency from some other service? Because If someone wants to change the frequency, I don't want it to be done via console.
Can someone help me solving this?

Comment: Here is two possible ways to change **any** AWS resources: 1. via console, 2. via CLI. Both depends on AWS IAM permissions. If you don't want to grant permissions to exact person then you have to grant permissions to some service that will be able to change schedule. But at first you have to develop this service and user interface (web page, mobile app, whatever). What kind of solution you expecting to see?

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 options, each one has same issue - you need to prevent access to the related resources...
https://betterprogramming.pub/cron-job-patterns-in-aws-126fbf54a276

---

In the case where you are the administrator of the AWS account, you may consider:

- deployment of the lambda function, and event bridge rule on another account, with access to this account, so users wouldn't be able to even see your function and rule.
- giving users permissions that will prevent access to your rule and lambda function.